# jquery scrolltop from Hash url

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

i want to the page to smooth scroll to an anchor based on the hash URL when the page loads.

ie

www.domain.com/pagename/#matches

I have this, but it's not working

```
var elem = $('#_' + window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
if(elem) {
     $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#' + elem).offset().top-65
        }, 1000);
        return false;
}
```

Console error is

Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

**Update**

I got it working with

```
if(window.location.hash) {
     var elem = window.location.hash;
     $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top-65
        }, 1000);
        return false;
}
```

However when the animation finishes, the default anchor action kicks in and thus jumps the page and ignores the offset im trying to achieve

Comment: share yur full code what you do

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then check if hash is found then extract it from url and pass it to `scrollTop`.

```
if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      $(document.body).animate({
          'scrollTop':   $('#' + hash).offset().top
      }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: thank you, i actually got it working with

if(window.location.hash) {
   var elem = window.location.hash;
   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top-65
   }, 1000);
   return false;
    }

trouble is, after the animation scroll it still does the normal anchor jump and thus removes the offset im trying to achieve